# Notation for "second level" element containment?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, convention

Suppose I have a family of sets $\mathcal{A}$.

Suppose that $x$ is contained in some set in $\mathcal{A}$.

Is there a common notation/convention for this relation? IE, $x \in_{\in} \mathcal{A}$?

I suppose the normal way to say that is something along the lines of "$\{x\}$ is covered by $\mathcal{A}$", but that's a little weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no single symbol that is commonly used to denote this.  However, one slick way you could write it is $x\in\bigcup\mathcal{A}$.  Here $\bigcup\mathcal{A}$ denotes the union of all the elements of $\mathcal{A}$, so $x\in\bigcup\mathcal{A}$ means exactly that $x$ is an element of some element of $\mathcal{A}$.